# Manage Master page in Page Layouts

Tags: page-layout

I am provisioning page layouts (html files) using Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate.
Template file snippet attached here.

After applying, getting "Warning and Errors" in Design Manager -> Edit Page Layout section.

When clicking on "Warnings and Errors", getting message as "This page layout's master page has changed, which will cause inconsistencies across your site. Click here to update the sections of your page layout that represent master page regions. "

Clicking on section resolve problem & change status as "Conversion Successful"

I want to automate these steps, like after applying templates using Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate, I should get status as "Conversion successful."

Please help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would discourage using HTML templates altogether and just deploy the .master and .aspx files directly. The HTML files conversion never works properly in a provisioning scenario, and in any case it doesn't make sense anyway. The HTML files are useful if you're going to have designers modifying those files post-deployment on the target sites, which isn't something that's typically done.

Comment: I am trying to provision .aspx files but its not showing changes. I asked question here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255910/pnp-provision-page-layout-in-sharepoint-online . Can you please tell me whats wrong I am doing ? Do you have any sample which I can use ?