# PnP Provision Page Layout in Sharepoint Online

Tags: page-layout, pnp-provision

I am provisioning Sharepoint online page layout changes using pnp provisioning. Steps performed are:

1- Go to SiteCollection->Design Manager-> Upload Design Files-> click on _catalog/masterpage/ link -> Get the .aspx of page layout (not considering .html of page layout)

2- Change javascript / html of pagelayout.aspx & modified provisioning template file as attached in screenshot.

3- Use pnp powershell command & run Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path $provisioningtemplatePath;

4- Running above command not throwing any error, but its not applying changes in Sharepoint Online sitecollection.

5- Please be noticed that I get contenttypeid and other details using Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out "template.xml" -PersistBrandingFiles -PersistPublishingFiles;
Can anyone help me how to remote provision page layout changes in Sharepoint online environment ? Whats wrong I am doing ? What changes I need to provision Page Layouts in Sharepoint Online environment ?

I can map drive for Design Manager & edit pagelayout.html & save it. This way its updating pagelayout.aspx as well. How to achieve it programmatically ?

My existing approach is provision using pagelayout.html but I am facing another problem which is mentioned here [Manage Master page in Page Layouts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255804/manage-master-page-in-page-layouts)

[image]

Comment: Please help me on this.